# send ctrl+D Remote Desktop on MAC to a windows PC in Excel

Tags: excel, macos, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, remote-desktop

I'm trying to drag down the formula from one cell to the entire column in excel using ctrl+d, but it is not working in my remote connection, Can someone please help me with it?

Answer (score 0):

You can even do it using `mouse` by just double clicking the `right-down-corner` of the cell. your cursor will become a plus as you see in the picture, once you see this just double click with your mouse. your formula will be copied to the entire column.

[image]